# Chrome App File I/O problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-app, browserify

I'm trying to load a pdf into an offline Chrome App using pdf.js and node.js (fs through browserify).

My problem is with file paths. I attempted a short test with the following code:

```
var fs = require('browserify-fs');

fs.mkdir('/home', function() {
    fs.writeFile('/home/hello-world.txt', 'Hello world!\n', function() {
        fs.readFile('/home/hello-world.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

It behaves exactly as it ought. On the console, I read 'Hello world!'. **My first problem: I DON'T HAVE ANY IDEA WHERE THAT FILE WAS CREATED?!?!** I've done searches all over my hard drive and can't find *hello-world.txt* anywhere. Where does the browserify-fs treat as root?

Second, I tried another test, using a bit of Chrome's I/O and node.js.

```
var fs = require('browserify-fs');
var path;

chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({'type': 'openFile'},
function( entry,  fileEntries) {
  chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(entry, function(displayPath){ 
    path = displayPath;
    console.log(path);
    fs.appendFile(path, 'data to append', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
    });
  });
});
```

As it should, Chrome prompts me to choose a file. After selecting, it prints a correct file path to the console (e.g., `"~/Downloads/foo.txt"`). But at this point, `fs.appendFile()` can't find that location. So, I thought, maybe it needs the path from root. So I manually passed it  `'/home/chronos/user/Downloads/foo.txt'` and `fs.appendFile()` still couldn't find the file.

So, this entire post was a long winded way of asking how node's fs-module handles paths, and where the root directory is located when I use browserify.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you're asking two different questions. Consider asking them separately so that your question tags can be applied correctly.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I think I need to regroup and take another stab at defining the problem before I start asking question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question seems to be about browserfy-fs, which I'm not familiar with, rather than about Chrome Apps. The code you show doesn't use any Chrome App APIs.

Your second question shows code in which chooseEntry provides a FileEntry object to its callback, and that's what you need to do I/O with, using the appropriate APIs (Google "FileEntry API"). Again, passing the path to browserfy-fs may or may not do anything useful, but whatever it does or doesn't do is a browserfy-fs question, and not a Chrome App question.

Is there some reason why you're trying to use browserfy-fs to do file I/O in a Chrome App?

Comment: Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree using browserfy. This morning, I tried simply using Chrome's file I/O, but I hit a wall when trying to do anything with local files. Additionally, I believed I needed to use node.js because research I did suggested that was the only was to get pdf.js to work in a packaged chrome app. Tough stuff...

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "hit a wall" means? Error message? Crash? Nonresponsive? Wrong data? Did you have the right permissions in your manifest.json? (I use jsPDF with Chrome Apps with great success.)

Comment: First, Thanks for helping with this. Second, I started working with this app.js script and it has helped me work with files outside of node's fs (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/filesystem-access/js/app.js). So, I think I'm headed in the right direction. Now that I'm opening and manipulating text files from my app, I'm going to tentatively tie in pdf.js and see if I can view pdf's that are opened from my file system. I'll report back if I run into anything weird. Thanks!